# See bugs in TFS 2015 Product Backlog Board

Tags: tfs

I have just upgraded an on-site TFS installation from 2013 to 2015. We will be changing the `working with bugs` setting to `Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks` instead of on the backlog board.

In the following image, we can see the Yellow task icon, along with a the number of tasks completed. However, there is no way to see if the item has any bugs associated with it.

[image: TFS PBI]

Is it possible to see bugs in the same way as tasks or to indicate if the item has  any bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of searching, it appears you cannot do this. You can have Tasks showing in the Item, but not Bugs.

If you select `Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks`, the only way to see the bugs is on the task board and there is no indication of open or closed bugs on the Backlog Board.

Answer (score 0):

When you track bugs similar to tasks, they’ll show up on the sprint backlogs and task boards.

When you track bugs as requirements, they'll show up on the product backlog and Kanban board.

You are tracking bugs similar to tasks, but you are checking Kanban board, so you can't see bugs. You need to check task boards.

Comment: But tasks show on the board, as you can see in the image above (6/6). Can I get bugs to show up the same way. If not, how do you know which items have bugs assigned?

Comment: Check task boards, or track bugs as requirements.

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround, but I want to see if it is possible to view the bugs in the task from the Backlog Board

Comment: Thanks @Cece. I have spent a lot of time on this and I don't think it is possible. Shame.